# 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

implementing a `<%= render @booking_types %>` partial in my **home#dashboard** view, Why is rails not looking into `app/views/booking_types` folder for a partial named `_booking_type.html.erb` and renders it as a looped instance?

## **app/views/home/dashboard.html.erb**

```rb
  <div class="flex items-center justify-between pb-6 border-b">

    <h1 class="font-extrabold text-3xl">Dashboard</h1>

    <%= link_to "Create booking type", new_booking_type_path, class: button_class(theme: "primary") %>

  </div>

  <div class="py-10 grid grid-cols-3 gap-6">

    <%= render @booking_types %>

  </div>

</div>
```

the partial

**app/views/booking_types/_booking_type.html.erb**

```rb
<div id="<%= dom_id booking_type %>">
  <%= link_to edit_booking_type_path(booking_type), class: "p-6 border shadow-xl rounded-xl block hover:shadow-lg transition ease-in duration-300 relative overflow-hidden" do %>
    <div class="h-1 w-full absolute top-0 left-0 right-0" style="background-color: <%= booking_type.color %>">
    </div>
    <h3 class="font-medium text-2xl"><%= booking_type.name %></h3>
    <p class="text-gray-500">View booking page</p>
    <p><%= duration(booking_type) %></p>

    <% if booking_type.payment_required? %>
      <div class="mt-3 pt-3 border-t">
        <p>
          <strong>Payment required</strong>
        </p>
        <p>
          <strong>Price:</strong>
          <%= number_to_currency(booking_type.price) %>
        </p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

[Error Output by better-errors gem after changing rendering partial from  `<%= render @booking_types %>` to this way
`<%= render "booking_types/booking_type" %>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nh4VW.png)

Comment: In order to determine what partial to render in this scenario, Rails calls [to_partial_path](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Conversion.html#method-i-to_partial_path) against each member of the rendered collection. The error suggests that at least one member of the `@booking_types` collection is `nil`. Is `@booking_types` populated with `BookingType` instances?

Comment: yes. so i tried rendering the partial this way `<%= render "booking_types/booking_type" %>`  and had this error `undefined local variable or method booking_type' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000013330>` from the partial

Comment: That's because you haven't provided any local arguments when rendering the partial, so `booking_type` is undefined. I still think your issue is with the `@booking_types` collection. I suggest setting a breakpoint in your app code that assigns this variable and seeing why it contains `nil` elements.

Comment: @RickRunyon my guess is that `@booking_types` its not even a collection at all as `render nil` will cause the exact same error message. As always with nil errors you need to ensure that you have actually set the instance variable in the controller and its not just a simple typo.